# Is it possible to put microsoft-graph client secret into source code?

Tags: javascript, oauth, electron, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a javascript electron app (https://github.com/damien122/cloudnoter) which should connect to Microsoft graph backend and provide access to OneNote notebooks.
Previously it works very well, but Microsoft changed the API, and I should adapt my app now.
Previously it was possible to get the Bearer token by code without using the client-secret, but now I should use the client secret and my question:

**Is it recommended to put the client secret into the source code? And also publish it on GitHub. What can someone can do with the client ID and client secret? Should I keep the client-secret really "secret"? Can I provide the client-secret to my app and keep it secret?**

In the app registration service from m.s. I registered the app as a web app because this is the only way to get the authentication for me. I can't find a way how to authenticate for web apps without the client secret. And can't find a way how to use the "Nativ/Mobile App" registration with javascript.
By the way, I use this documentation -> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

Comment: The "implicit auth" flow (from your screenshot) should not require a secret, unless Microsoft is not compliant with OAuth2.

Comment: You also should not be able to refresh with implicit auth. Is it possible you're using the 'wrong' oauth flow?

Comment: In the documentation is also written that the secret is o ly required when you use a webapp. And this the case in my app. Which flow do you mean?

Comment: I use the flow to request at first the authorization code and with that code I should request the bearer token. And the second step needs the client secret, otherwise I got an grant error from the backend.

Comment: That is the Authorization Code grant, not the Implicit grant (which is what you want). You should be using Implicit with a native app (or use Auth Code from your own backend server to proxy calls to Graph). Also, the answer is an unequivocal No. You should _never_ put your secret on the client.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur is this what you mean? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow

Comment: @MarcLaFleur But I don't understand how to use my javascript app with an nativ app regestration. Also I don't have an own backend, the app is all on client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the grant flow, please check it as @Event and @Marc suggested.

And for your other questions.

> Is it recommended to put the client secret into the source code? And
> also publish it on GitHub.

**No**

> What can someone can do with the client ID and client secret?

**With the Client ID and client secret, someone may call the resource in your data store. But some case need we also pass the app name in the request.**

> Should I keep the client-secret really "secret"?

**Yes**

> Can I provide the client-secret to my app and keep it secret?

**Yes**. You can use the **[Azure KeyValut](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)** to protect your secret. Or just following the below blog:

> https://medium.com/poka-techblog/the-best-way-to-store-secrets-in-your-app-is-not-to-store-secrets-in-your-app-308a6807d3ed
>
> **Storing secrets in the environment**
>
> stripe_api_key = os.environ["STRIPE_API_KEY"]
>
> **Storing secrets in the database**
> **Using a secrets syncing service**
>
> **Storing secrets in your code …but encrypted**

Comment: thanks for your response. It sounds like what I was looking for. do you have maybe a link with more information about how to provide the client secret and keep it secret?

Comment: Update my answer. Basicly, do not provide the secret key in code directly.

Comment: thanks for your  fast response. At first I will try the Implicit grant and if this will not work, I will try your solution. But mainly you answere my questions, thanks.